# How to make 3 level multicoloum in pandas while concatenating different df

Tags: pandas

I have two main blocks to build a pandas data frame. One block is pretty simple, while the other is build from several pandas data frames, which are all alike. At the end I would like to concatenate them and have a three multicolumn level header.

Let me add an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[["v1", "v2", "v3"], ["v4", "v5", "v6"]], columns=["c1", "c2", "c3"], index=["ID1", "ID2"])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0]], columns=["n1", "n2", "n3"], index=["ID1", "ID2"])
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0, 0, 0], [4, 5, 6]], columns=["n1", "n3", "n3"], index=["ID1", "ID2"])
```

here `df_1` is the first building block. While `df_2` and `df_3` belong to the second building block and are alike. They might be more, but two are sufficient. I would like to concatenate them, which is already an issue as the dfs from the second block have identical columns. That's why I want a multicolumn data frame. At the end, I would like to have the following:

[image]

Ideally I can center the Title and `df_x` headers. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `MultiIndex` in `df_1` too for possible `concat` new `df` DataFrame - in another words is necessary join DataFrames with same levels of `MultiIndex in columns`:

```
df = pd.concat([df_2, df_3], axis=1, keys=('df2','df3'))

df_1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['df1'], df_1.columns])
df = pd.concat([df_1, df], axis=1, keys=('title1','title2'))
print (df)
    title1         title2                
       df1            df2       df3      
        c1  c2  c3     n1 n2 n3  n1 n3 n3
ID1     v1  v2  v3      1  2  3   0  0  0
ID2     v4  v5  v6      0  0  0   4  5  6
```

Comment: Excellent, many thanks! Is there a way to center the multiindex so that its not left aligned?

Comment: @math it is default displaying of MultiIndex, I not sure if possible change.